# How to output HTML in angularjs with just using filter

Tags: angularjs, filter

I'm able to unescape the string that has some markup in it using `ngSanitize` and in HTML I use

```
<span ng-bind-html="myHTML"></span>
```

I've created a filter

```
.filter('safe', function($sce) {
    return function(val) {
      return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
  };
})
```

I wonder if I can do something like this instead?

```
<span>{{ myHTML | safe }}</span>
```

Right now it does not really work and I'm trying to see what I'm missing.

Comment: Are you getting that "HTML not allowed" angular error?

Comment: No error at all except is just print like regular strings

Answer (score 2):

You can make your own filter for that:

```
var app = angular.module('yourModuleName');
app.filter('safe', function($sce) {
    return function(htmlString) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(htmlString);
    }
};
```

Your markup would be something like:

```
<span ng-bind-html="myHTML | safe"></span>
```

Comment: That's what I currently have but I'm looking for making it like example above

Comment: So,  like if I don't use ng-bind-html is that possible to do so?

Comment: I really don't think so. {{ }} inside elements get evaluated and shown as strings (the element's text).

Comment: If you could, there would be no need for $sce, you could just place some html in a span and get it rendered...

Comment: True on that part except I'm injecting this from a JSON file :(

Comment: And what's the problem with that? Why can't you use the ng-bind-html?